# Property setter not getting called with CollectionEditor

Tags: c#, winforms, uitypeeditor, collectioneditor

I have a custom control that has an `Items` property. I Have applied an `EditorAttribute` with a `UITypeEditor` of type `CollectionEditor`.

**Collection Type:**

```
[Serializable]
[Editor(typeof(CollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public class ListItemsCollection : CollectionBase
{
    // methods
}
```

**Property Declaration In The Control:**

```
private new ListItemsCollection _Items;

[Editor(typeof(CollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public new ListItemsCollection Items
{
    get
    {
        return _Items;
    }
    set
    {
        _Items = value;

        // do other UI changes
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
When I drop this control to the designer surface, I am able to add items to the Items property using the `PropertyGrid`. But, the when I click the `Ok` button of the `CollectionEditor` the setter of the `Items` property is not getting called.

AFAIK when a value is returned from the `EditValue` method of a `UITypeEditor` class the setter block of the property is supposed to be called.

This is driving me insane. I even tried adding `Event`'s to the `ListItemsCollection`, so that when Items are added, I can whatever I want with the control's ui.

**This is not supposed to be hard. What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to reprodeuce your situation: using following code, I get a message box showing whenever I edit the list from VS property window. Beware that you have to create the list by yourself. If you don't create it, VS create a temp list which you can edit from property window, but does not set your property to this list (so your setter will never be called)

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list = new BindingList<ListViewItem>();
        list.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(list_ListChanged);
    }

    void list_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ListChangedType.ToString());
    }

    private BindingList<ListViewItem> list;

    public BindingList<ListViewItem> List1
    {
        get { return list; }
    }
```

Comment: BindingList works fine .. but I had to extend BindingList & CollectionEditor in order to raise the ListChanged event once the OK button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Collection properties should be read-only. It's the collection that is retrieved through the getter, and adjusted. The setter never enters into it, because that would mean setting a new collection.

Comment: How do I do certain operation when the collection is modified using the CollectionEditor?

Comment: You could only know if your collection itself has any events, which is not often the case, and definitely not in a ListItemCollection. You could try and write your own collection, or inherit from ListItemCollection, and override the add, delete, insert methods to invoke an event you defined yourself, after being called.